# Is it possible to use build Windows Phone projects using Team Foundation Service's hosted build agents?

Tags: continuous-integration, windows-phone, azure-devops

I'm trying to get a solution containing a Windows Phone app to build on check-in to Team foundation Service (i.e. the hosted service), however it is failing with errors like:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight for Phone\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets (200): The "CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>   File name: 'PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Is it just the case that Windows Phone apps aren't supported for builds, or do I need to apply some magic to the build template?

Comment: Is the appropriate SDK installed on the build server?

Comment: The build server is provided for me as part of Team Foundation Service (NB: The cloud hosted version) subscription. I cannot even log on to it to verify what SDKs may be installed, however the list at http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/hosted-build-controller-in-vs.aspx#software implies Windows Phone 8 apps should work (mine happens to be a Windows Phone 7 app, though I believe the 8 SDK to be backwardly compatible?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Windows Phone 8 SDK, then you should be good to go according to the current list of software that is installed on the hosted build servers on the Team Foundation Service:  http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/hosted-build-controller-in-vs.aspx#software.

Comment: I saw tha the WP8SDK is on there; in my case I'm trying to target WP7.8, so I can only assume that the SDK is not backwardly compatible (and I'd rather target WP7.x then get CI working, for the time being).

Comment: Right - You can setup your own build server and connect it to the Team Foundation Service with what you need for the Windows Phone 7.8 SDK to get it going for you.